# Show that $\frac{1-\cos2 \theta}{\sin2 \theta} = \tan \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I have to show that the left equation simplifies to $\tan\theta$:

> Show that:
>   $$\frac{1-\cos2 \theta}{\sin2 \theta} = \tan \theta$$

I do have prior knowledge that:
$$\tan \theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos \theta}$$

But I'm stuck from this point, I have tried a few rules, but none have seemed to work so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the double angle formulae:

$$\cos(2\theta)=1-2\sin^2\theta$$
$$\sin(2\theta)=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$$

$$\frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{\sin(2\theta)}=\frac{1-1+2\sin^2\theta}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}=\frac{2\sin^2\theta}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\tan\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

you need the double angle formulae 
$
cos2\theta=2cos^2\theta-1$ and $
sin2\theta=2sin\theta cos\theta 
$

Comment: you can prove those from sin(a+b) cos(a+b) expressions

Answer (score 1):

use $cos2\theta$=$1-2{sin^2{\theta}}$ and $sin2\theta$=$2{sin\theta}{cos\theta}$ and you will get your required answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed answer.
**Let's go!**
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\frac{1-\cos2\theta}{\sin2\theta}&=\frac{1-\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}\\
&=\frac{1-\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}\\
&=\frac{\sin^2\theta\cancel{+\cos^2\theta}\cancel{-\cos^2\theta}+\sin^2\theta}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}\\
&=\frac{\bcancel2\cancelto{\sin\theta}{\sin^2\theta}}{\bcancel2\cancel{\sin\theta}\cos\theta}\\
&=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\\
&=\tan\theta
\end{align}
$$
I hope this helps.